# Slide multiple edges toward/away from each other

Tags: modeling

I often run into the problem that I want to slide multiple edges away from each other. Sometimes there are simple workarounds like scaling, but other times it's not an option. I tried to make an example in the image where this is clear. (Of course there are work arounds here too, but I want to learn the tool).

I think what I have in mind is similar to the push/pull tool. Like I choose a bunch of edges, hit G twice, and then make sure it's push or pull based on the pivot point.

I'd be willing to pay for an addon if it has that feature.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would be a kind of Affect Only Locations option in Edit mode, I don't think there's any direct way to do it, only indirect ways, in the case you show I would individually glide each edge with GG

Comment: That's what I do now. Slide one, copy the number and paste for the other edge. There are times though when I might have quite a lot of edges and this becomes very tedious.

Comment: Affect only locations with scaling would move them away, but I think he wants to edge slide them away, so that is different from just moving away from each other or moving based on normals. It would need to be based on nearby edges so it would be an edge/vertex slide tool with some sort of constraining based on normals maybe... I think it would be useful to have, but I don't think there is any functionality for that and I don't think there is any addon that would have such functionality...